# Unity Facebook : 400 Bad Request

Tags: facebook, https, unity-game-engine, pageload

I using following code to get user data from facebook

```
IEnumerator UserFBDataGet(string accessTkn)
{
    var  downloader3 = new WWW (  "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,email&access_token="+accessTkn  );
    //Application.OpenURL (  "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,email&access_token="+accessTkn  );
    yield return downloader3;
    print(" downloader3.text  ="+downloader3.text );
    if(downloader3.error == null)
    {
        print(" downloader3.text  ="+downloader3.text );
    }
    else
    {
        print(" downloader3.error  ="+downloader3.error );
    }

}
```

It showing Error

You are trying to load data from a www stream which had the following error when downloading.
400 Bad Request
UnityEngine.WWW:get_text()
c__Iterator1:MoveNext() (at Assets/FBDesktopManager.cs:126)

Even i use WWWForm same error is showing

```
IEnumerator UserFBDataGet(string accessTkn)
{

    userDataGetUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?";

    WWWForm  wf = new WWWForm();

    wf.AddField ("fields","id,name,email") ;
    wf.AddField ("access_token",accessTkn) ;

    WWW  downloader3 = new WWW(userDataGetUrl,wf) ;

        yield return downloader3;

    print(" downloader3.text  ="+downloader3.text );
            if(downloader3.error == null)
            {
                print(" downloader3.text  ="+downloader3.text );
            }
            else
            {
                print(" downloader3.error  ="+downloader3.error );
            }


}
```

But when I call

```
Application.OpenURL (  "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,email&access_token="+accessTkn  );
```

in that page i get all data properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your url needs to be '%' escaped. Besides unity suggests using [WWWForm](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html) to pass POST parameters properly.

Comment: same error is getting even it change to WWWForm  new code is added above

Comment: Anyone know solution for this WWW Class problem .Please help me